# Errors When Setting Custom Android Theme

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

I get an error when I try to set the theme via the AndroidManifest. The error, at build time, is "**No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@styles/MainApplicationStyle')**"

I have cleaned the project, and rebuilt it several times. I am also getting messages and warnings from the compiler that follow the form of "Could not find schema information for the element '(attribute here).' All these messages and warnings come from the AndroidManifest.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          package="TheTipApp.TheTipApp" android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="TheTipApp" />
    <application android:theme="@styles/MainApplicationStyle"/>
</manifest>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MainApplicationStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

I have also tried to set the theme in the AssemblyInfo.cs file, not sure if it may be creating a problem.

**AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("TheTipApp")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("TheTipApp")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2017")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: Application(Theme = "@styles/MainApplicationStyle")]

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

I am not sure if this has anything to do with this either, but I also have **Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat**, and **Xamarin.Android.Support.v4** installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `@style` instead of `@styles`. Secondly, you should only have one `<application>` node in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

> Only the `<manifest>` and `<application>` elements are required. They each must be present and can occur only once.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filec

Comment: Does that mean **values\styles.xml** needs to be renamed to **values\style.xml** too?

Comment: Nope. You can put a `style` in any custom named `.xml` file. `styles.xml` is just a convention for where you would put your custom theme at.